# Template prefix for emplace method

Tags: c++, c++20, clion

When i'm trying to use emplace method of `unordered_map` my IDE (CLion 2021.1.2 Build #CL-211.7442.42) inserts a `template` keyword before `emplace` method. I don't get it why it is used in my case? Example:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Store {
public:
  void Set(std::string const& key, T value) {
    storage_.template emplace(key, std::move(value));
  }
private:
  std::unordered_map<std::string, T> storage_;
};
```

Comment: Not sure which IDE you're using... but `template` shouldn't be there.

Comment: @mgetz CLIon (intellij idea)

Comment: Something strange - compiles with clang and gcc, but not with MSVC - live - https://godbolt.org/z/EoWTMecKs  Perhaps add [language-lawyer] as we have compiler differences ?

Comment: If I had to guess it's because `std::unordered_set::emplace` is itself a templated member function https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/emplace so it could be a dependant name.

Comment: @RichardCritten AFAIK that would trigger `typename`? I've never seen `template` used that way, or even heard of needing it.

Comment: @Mgetz _"...Inside a declaration or a definition of a template, typename can be used to declare that a dependent qualified name is a type...."_ - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/typename Still it's not a type so I am still with "something strange"

Comment: @RichardCritten I'm well aware of `typename` I mean using `template` like that.

Comment: @Mgetz oops my mistake sorry.

Comment: @Mgetz how about _"...Inside a template definition, template can be used to declare that a dependent name is a template..."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/template and this matches because `std::unordered_set::emplace` is a member template.

Comment: so based on the linked question it seems this use of the `template` keyword is obsolete largely.